# HTML : draw table using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML += "<table border=1 width=100%><tr>";
for(j=1;j<=10;j++)
{
    document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML += "<td align=center>"+String.fromCharCode(j+64)+"</td>";
}
document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML += "</tr></table>";
```

I want to draw a table using Javascript.
So I wrote the code like above.
I think it draw one row that has 10 columns, but it doesn't work.
Anyone know about this problem???

Answer (score 36):

I ran into this problem years ago, too.

The problem is that when you use the `innerHTML` property to add HTML, after each update, the underlying engine will close unclosed tag (and fix other bad HTML) for you. So after the second line, the `<table>` and `<tr>` tags are automatically closed and all content after that will just be written outside the table.

---

**Method 1**
(The easy way)

Use a string to store the HTML for the whole table and update it all at once.

```
var HTML = "<table border=1 width=100%><tr>";
for(j=1;j<=10;j++)
{
    HTML += "<td align=center>"+String.fromCharCode(j+64)+"</td>";
}
HTML += "</tr></table>";
document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = HTML;
```

​
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfmeg/)

---

**Method 2**
(The better way)

Use DOM functions

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.setAttribute('border','1');
table.setAttribute('width','100%')
var row = table.insertRow(0);
for(j=1; j<=10; j++){
    var text = document.createTextNode(String.fromCharCode(j+64));
    var cell = row.insertCell(j-1);
    cell.setAttribute('align','center')
    cell.appendChild(text);
}
document.getElementById("outputDiv").appendChild(table);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfmeg/1/)

---

**Method 2 enhanced**
(The yet better way)

Use [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS) instead of HTML attributes. Using HTML attributes for styling is generally discouraged.

A great resource to start learning CSS is the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfmeg/2/)

---

**Method 3**
(<s>The long way, but the best in the long-run</s> Alternative)

**UPDATE**: It has been more than 10 years since I wrote this answer, and the webdev scene has changed *a lot* in the meantime. Because this answer still gets occasional upvotes, I am writing this to inform anyone who stumble upon this that using jQuery *everywhere* is no longer considered best practice. **Method 2** above (a.k.a. Vanilla) is good enough for small/throwaway/learning projects and whether to use Vanilla or jQuery or a framework should be a conscious choice after learning the pros and cons.

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

```
$('<table>').append('<tr>').appendTo('#outputDiv');
for(j=1; j<=10; j++)
    $('<td>').text(String.fromCharCode(j+64)).appendTo('tr');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfmeg/3/)

Comment: +1 - I was wondering if that unclosed <table> and <tr> tags would cause problems.  Good to know.

Comment: @Jimmy - this answer is way better than mine - make sure you upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem is that your attributes are not quoted.

But it's almost always a bad idea to repeatedly update the content of a dom element in a loop—each time you update dom content it causes some internal work to be done by the browser to make sure the page layout is current.

I would build the html string up locally, then make one final update when done.  (and of course make sure your attributes are quoted)

```
document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = "";

var newTable = "<table border='1' width='100%'><tr>";
for(j = 1; j <= 10; j++) { //opening braces should always be on the same line in JS
    newTable += "<td align='center'>" + String.fromCharCode(j+64) + "</td>";
}
newTable += "</tr></table>";

document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = newTable;
```