# How to convert HTML table to Javascript

Tags: javascript

So as a beginner, I have no idea how to create a table using Javascript. I can make a table using a simple html file but not in Javascript.

The output should have 2 columns and 4 rows. I also need to use the prompt tag in order to insert data for the second column. Not to mention that I need to average the total number in the 2nd column.

I tried searching but I got mixed results and its confusing me.so please help me

this is the html file

```
<html>
    <body>

    <table border="1" style="width:30%">
        <tr>
            <td>Rose</td>

            <td>40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Daisy</td>

            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Orchids</td>

            <td>60</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Flowers</td>
            <td>150</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775519/html-draw-table-using-innerhtml OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643617/create-table-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this - >

```js
var Rose = prompt("Enter price for Rose?");
var Daisy = prompt("Enter price for Daisy?");
var Orchids = prompt("Enter price for Orchids?");

var flowers = Number(Rose) + Number(Daisy) + Number(Orchids);

var table = document.createElement("table");

createTable();

function createTable(){
    createTrTds("Rose",Rose);
    createTrTds("Daisy",Daisy);
    createTrTds("Orchids",Orchids);
    createTrTds("Total",flowers);
  document.getElementById("table").appendChild(table);
}


function createTrTds(text,value){
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");   
    
    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
    var td2 = document.createElement("td");
    
    var txt1 = document.createTextNode(text);
    var txt2 = document.createTextNode(value);
    
    td1.appendChild(txt1);
    td2.appendChild(txt2);
    
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    
    table.appendChild(tr);
    
}
```

```css
td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be helped by using a framework for this, jquery or angularjs comes to mind to solve it. However the pure JavaScript way looks like this:

This will create a table with inputs for the number of flowers and sum them up at the bottom when numbers change, you can also add more flower types in the JavaScript file.

```js
var tabledef = [];
tabledef['Rose'] = 40;
tabledef['Daisy'] = 50;
tabledef['Orchids'] = 60;

writeTable();

function writeTable() {
  var table = '<table border="1" style="width:30%">';
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i in tabledef) {
    sum = sum + tabledef[i];
    table = table + '<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td><input id="' + i + '" onchange="recalculate(this)" type="number" value="' + tabledef[i] + '"></td></tr>';
  }
  table = table + '<tr><td>Flowers</td><td>' + sum + '</td></tr></table>';
  document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = table;
}

function recalculate(box) {
  tabledef[box.id] = box.valueAsNumber;
  writeTable();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myTable"></div>
  <script src="createTable.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need array with data and then fill table as thought it was an html document

```
var table = '<table border="1">',
    data = [['Rose','Daisy','Orchids','Flowers'],[40,50,60,150]];

for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    table += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        table += '<td>' + data[j][i] + '</td>';
    }
    table += '</tr>';
}
table += '</table>';
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = table;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5pdac6sb/