# innerHTML doesn't generate <tr> and <td> properly

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I need to generate a table whose tbody's rows are generate through a for(). Because in this rows will be data coming from an array.

This is my code:

**JS:**

```
alunos = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                document.getElementById("tableModal").innerHTML =
                    "<div class='table-responsive'>"+
                    "<table class='table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-order'>"+
                    "<thead>"+
                    "<tr>"+
                    "<th>Aluno</th>"+
                    "<th>Celular</th>"+
                    "<th>Turma</th>"+
                    "<th>Status</th>"+
                    "</tr>"+
                    "</thead>"
                    "<tbody>";
                for(i = 0; i<alunos.length;i++) {
                    document.getElementById("tableModal").innerHTML +=
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + alunos[i].nome + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + alunos[i].celular + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + turma + "</td>" +
                    "<td>Status</td>" +
                    "</tr>";

                }
                document.getElementById("tableModal").innerHTML += "</tbody></table></div>";
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalMsg" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="tituloModal"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="tableModal"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Until the for statement, everything works as I want. But the tr and the td are not generated.

Comment: Translate it to English please

Comment: I translated it.

Comment: One error I notice right away: assigning to `innerHTML` already parses the DOM, but due to a lacking `</tbody>` and other missing things, the DOM is parsed incorrectly. So add everything from your table in a string first, and only at the very end assign that string to `.innerHTML`.

Comment: What browser? Internet Explorer? If so, its parser has trouble with certain elements.

Comment: I just tested on Chrome until now.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [HTML : draw table using innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13775519/4642212).

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that you were trying to add HTML in "before and after" segments. That isn't how a DOM works. You need to describe *complete* elements in your HTML when giving them to `.innerHTML`.

Comment: @Xufox I didn't know. Sorry.

Comment: @rockstar now it worked. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: And sorry for the bad translation at the beggining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it in one go:

```js
var req = {
  responseText : '[{"nome":"name","celular":"1233456"},{"nome":"name","celular":"1233456"}]'
}
var turma = "x";
alunos = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
var html= "<div class='table-responsive'>" +
  "<table class='table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-order'>" +
  "<thead>" +
  "<tr>" +
  "<th>Aluno</th>" +
  "<th>Celular</th>" +
  "<th>Turma</th>" +
  "<th>Status</th>" +
  "</tr>" +
  "</thead>"
"<tbody>";
for (i = 0; i < alunos.length; i++) {
  html +=
    "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + alunos[i].nome + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + alunos[i].celular + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + turma + "</td>" +
    "<td>Status</td>" +
    "</tr>";

}
document.getElementById("tableModal").innerHTML += html+"</tbody></table></div>";
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modalMsg" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="tituloModal"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="tableModal"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked!! Thanks!! I will just accept your answer.

Comment: It's ok. You can delete your question since it is already a duplicate - I only posted to show you specifically

Comment: Thanks, anyway! I can't delete it because there are answers in the question.