# Table will not be able to generate using Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is for a web app that will take in a survey I am using firebase. What I need help in is when the app is exporting the data into a table it grabs the data but won't is able to push it to the table any help would be appreciated. Since the HTML code is a long one I will only put the table portion:
the table portion of the HTML file

```
   <div id = "table">
   <pre id =  "snap-test"></pre>
  <table id ="File-Table" class="table">
         <thead>
          <tr>
          '<td><button onclick = "DeleteTabele()" id = "Delete-btn">Delete File</button></td>'
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <button onclick ="Return()" id= "Log-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-">Add a new File</button>
      </table>
    </div>
```

the Table.js file

```
 var table = document.getElementById("File-Table");
  const file = $("#File").val();
  var requests = [];
function Export(){
    //calls the file id in the HTML element 
  $("#Survey-Page").hide();
  $("#File-Table").show();
  $("#Log-btn").show();
  var result = [];
//calls the database from the firebase known as users then using a function we nest a snapshot in it for later 
  firebase.database().ref('/users/').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
  //if snapshot is empty then the window will alert 
   if (snapshot.val() == null){
        alert("Does not exist");
   }
   // if the snapshot is full then it will genereate a table based on the snapshot value of the database 
    else {
      console.log(snapshot.val());

        let result = snapshot.val()
      for(let k in result){
        this.requests.push({
          id: k,
          value: result[k]
        });
      }
     var MyTable = '<tr>' +
          '<td>' + snapshot.val().txtName  +'</td>' +
          '<td>' + snapshot.val().txtEmail +'</td>' +
          '<td>' + snapshot.val().FileName + '</th>' +
          '<td><button id = "Email-btn">Send Survey</button></td>' +
          '<td><button onclick = "DeleteTabele()" id = "Delete-btn">Delete File</button></td>' +
            '</tr>';
     MyTable += "</tr></table>";
      table.innerHTML = MyTable;

    }

    console.log(snapshot.val());

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you have published, the more probable cause is that your reference is referencing a node of multiple users and not a specific user.

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/')
```

To confirm this assumption we need to see your database structure. Can you edit you post?

However, let's imagine this assumption is correct. Then you have two solutions:

1. If you want to display the value of ONE user which is under the `users` node, you have to change the reference and point to this user, e.g.:

   firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userID)

Then the rest of the code will work normally

2. If you want to display in your table the entire list of users (one by row) you have to loop over the results of the query, as follow:

   ```
   firebase.database().ref('/so').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
   var MyTable;

   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
       MyTable += '<tr>' +
           '<td>' + childSnapshot.val().txtName +'</td>' +
           '<td>' + childSnapshot.val().txtEmail +'</td>' +
           // ...
           '<td><button id = "Email-btn">Send Survey</button></td>' +
           '<td><button onclick = "DeleteTabele()" id = "Delete-btn">Delete File</button></td>' +
           '</tr>';
        });
        table.innerHTML = MyTable;
   });
   ```

See the doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events

---

In addition, if I may, you could have a look at this SO post: [HTML : draw table using innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775519/html-draw-table-using-innerhtml?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) which shows some best practices for writing rows of a table in "simple" JavaScript.