# Refresh <table> HTML without refresh entire page Javascript Only

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how can i refresh my  without refresh the entire page in **Javascript**

Exemple of HTML

```
<table class="list" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="checkbox edit"></td>
                <td class="Element sortable" onclick="My.Game.List.sort(223, 'eleemnt');">Element</td>
                <td class="ew sortable" onclick="My.Game.List.sort(223, 'ew');">Pop.</td>
                <td class="distance sortable" onclick="My.Game.RaidList.sort(223, 'distance');">Distance</td>
                <td class="element sortable" onclick="My.Game.List.sort(223, 'element');">Option</td>
                <td class="last sortable" onclick="My.Game.List.sort(223, 'last');">Last</td>
                <td class="action"></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             <tr class="slotRow" id="slot-row-3021">
        <td class="checkbox">
            <input id="slot3021" name="slot[3021]" type="checkbox" class="markSlot check" onclick="My.Game.List.markSlot(223, 3021, this.checked);">
        </td>
        <td class="element">

                <a href="position_details.php?x=59&amp;y=14">Artic</a>
        </td>
        <td class="ew">
            31          </td>
        <td class="distance">
            2.2         </td>
        <td class="Option">
            <div class="icon"><img class="unit u11" alt="My ALt" src="img/x.gif"><span class="MyClass">2</span></div>           </td>
        <td class="last">
                                    <img src="img/x.gif" class="My Class"> // Might Change
                                                <img src="img/x.gif" class="carry full" alt="My Alt // Might Change
                    <a href="berichte.php?id=159141|bb7215c9">18.09.18, 15:26</a> // Change
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </td>
        <td class="action">
            <a class="arrow" href="#" onclick="My.Game.List.editSlot(223, 3021, true, 'rallyPoint'); return false;">Éditer</a>
        </td>
    </tr>               
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Basicly i would like to refresh the content of all the row of my Table

I tried this but it seems not working i don't understand why :

JAVASCRIPT CODE :

```
 setInterval(function() {

                document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].reload();

                }, 500);
```

NB : The function is just a timer to refresh the table each 500 ms.

What is excepted to change :

```
<tr class="slotRow" id="slot-row-3021">
            <td class="checkbox">
                <input id="slot3021" name="slot[3021]" type="checkbox" class="markSlot check" onclick="My.Game.List.markSlot(223, 3021, this.checked);">
            </td>
            <td class="element">

                    <a href="position_details.php?x=59&amp;y=14">Artic</a>
            </td>
            <td class="ew">
                31          </td>
            <td class="distance">
                2.2         </td>
            <td class="Option">
                <div class="icon"><img class="unit u11" alt="My ALt" src="img/x.gif"><span class="MyClass">2</span></div>           </td>
            <td class="last">
                                        <img src="img/x.gif" class="My Class"> // Might Change
                                                    <img src="img/x.gif" class="carry full" alt="My Alt // Might Change
                        <a href="berichte.php?id=159141|bb7215c9">18.09.18, 15:26</a> // Change
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </td>
            <td class="action">
                <a class="arrow" href="#" onclick="My.Game.List.editSlot(223, 3021, true, 'rallyPoint'); return false;">Éditer</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Best regards !

Comment: Why would you refresh static content ?

Comment: Because `reload()` is for a page, not a section of a page

Comment: @Seblor because the content isn't static it was just for the exemple ;)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney so what may i use ?

Comment: Then you need to tell us what is dynamic. Have you tried getting your data with a `fetch` request then building the HTML ?

Comment: We understand you're trying to refresh part of a page, but you need to let us know what you expect to change.

Comment: Also let us know where you expect the new data to come from.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I edited my post; This is only 1 row of my table but i got several row like this. I think i don't need to put the full table.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers to your question.

You could simply fix this by replacing the (inner)HTML of the element any time an update takes place.

Something like [HTML : draw table using innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775519/html-draw-table-using-innerhtml/13775575)

Messy, but it is the answer to your question.

Your HTML is not dynamicly updating values, that would be done trough javascript. If you are getting your values from a webservice - look into AJAX.

Comment: @Rheijn i just red your link but i don't understand it.